# How to integrate Indian Language with tinymce 4.0.12

Tags: tinymce-4

I am using `tinymce` 4.0.12 in my wicket project, I have a plugin for Indian language like:

`PramukhIme` and `IndicIme` in my `tinymce` plugin folder, but these plugins are created according to the older version of tinymce and new version of `tinymce` has changed its structure to read its plugin.

My tiny initiation code is:

```
tinyMCE.init({
                mode : "exact",        
                elements : "textarea",      
                theme : "modern",
                language :"en",
                plugins :pramukhime,
                toolbar1 :"pramukhime,pramukhimeclick,pramukhimeconvert,pramukhimehelp"
});
```

Is there any way or other plugins according to the new structure of tinymce so that i can use it?

Comment: This isn't relaed to wicket any more than it's related to Java or the Webserver the application is running on.

Comment: @Nicktar: The fact is that i want to integrate new tinymce in my wicket application, older version of (tinymce 3.5.8) is working fine.And what do you mean by it is not related to wicket as they have(tinymce) no dependency with any languages or framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i have done it without using any third party plugin in TinyMCE 4!

Note: Few things you have to keep in mind:

1. The language works upon the fonts installed in your OS.
2. Download valid fonts: Indian -> Regional fonts and install it in your OS.
3. Make sure all the installed fonts are proper and valid and downloaded from a proper source.

If you are using Windows, the installation path would be like this:

C:\Windows\Fonts\

Code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
                    mode : "exact",        
                    elements : "textarea",      
                    theme : "modern",
                    toolbar: "fontselect",
                 font_formats:"SCiRound=SCiRound;Shonarb=Shonarb;Shonar=Shonar;vrindab=vrindab;Vrinda=Vrinda;Devanagari New=Devanagari New;Kruti Dev=Kruti Dev;Kalpurush ANSI=Kalpurush ANSI;Aruna=Aruna;Haritha=Haritha"

});
```

Comment: hi, i tried the similar way, but it didn't work for me with Kruti Dev and DevLys fonts. [I asked the question about the same here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185765/how-to-integrate-indian-language-hindi-in-tinymce-4-x). How did you make tinymce work with hindi  fonts? thanks.

Comment: @ Dr. Atul Tiwari: check out the fonts Kruti Dev and DevLys by double clicking it from C:\Windows\Fonts. Whether fonts contains Hindi content or not. In case if fonts contain English paragraph, then it will not work. Try to download fonts from this [link](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and try again.

Comment: I checked my C:\Windows|Fonts. Both Kruti Dev and DevLys contains hindi contents. but they are not working with tinymce. Also I checked fontsquirrel, but I couldn't find hindi fonts there.

Comment: I have done same thing but not working in version4.x.